# How do I create a list of vectors in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm writing an Rcpp module an would like to return as one element of the RcppResultSet list a list whose elements are vectors.   E.g., `.Call("myfunc")$foo` should be something like:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1
```

(the exact numbers are not important here).  The issue is that I don't know the right Rcpp way of doing this.  I tried passing a `vector<vector<int> >` but this constructs a matrix by silently taking the length of the first vector as the width (even if the matrix is ragged!).  I've tried constructing an `RcppList` but have a hard time casting various objects (like `RcppVector`) safely into `SEXP`s.

Anyone have tips on best practices for dealing with complicated structures such as lists of vectors in Rcpp?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[ Nice to see this here but Romain and I generally recommend the [rccp-devel](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel) list for question. Please post there going forward as the project is not yet that large it warrants to have questions scattered all over the web. ]

`RcppResultSet` is part of the older *classic* API whereas a lot of work has gone into what we call the *new* API (starting with the 0.7.* releases).  Have a look at the current [Rcpp page on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) and the list of vignettes -- six and counting.

With new API you would return something like

```
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("vec") = someVector,
                          Rcpp::Named("lst") = someList,
                          Rcpp::Named("vec2") = someOtherVector);
```

all in one statement (and possibly using explicit `Rcpp::wrap()` calls), creating what in [R](http://www.r-project.org) would be

```
list(vec=someVector, lst=someList, vec2=someOtherVector)
```

And `Rcpp::List` should also be able to do lists of lists of lists... though I am not sure we have unit tests for this --- but there are numerous examples in the 500+ unit tests.

As it happens, I spent the last few days converting a lot of [RQuantLib](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib) code from the classic API to the new API. This will probably get released once we get version 0.8.3 of [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) out (hopefully in a few days). In the meantime, you can look at the [RQuantLib SVN archive](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/RQuantLib/?root=rquantlib)

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Everything works if you stick to the new `Rcpp::...` classes!

Comment: Cool indeed. I still need to cook up new classes `Rcpp::Date` and `Rcpp::Datetime` --- but you can definitely live without the old `RcppParams`, `RcppResultSet`, `RcppVector`, ... etc.  Feel free to contribute new unit tests or examples, or additions to the docs.  See you on `rcpp-devel` then :)

Comment: You makes my life easier. Although it's been a few days since I learned Rcpp but I can't imagine going back to combo of R & C.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Hope to see you over on rcpp-devel if you have questions.

Comment: Does your statement about preferring rcpp-devel still apply?

Comment: Yes it does. Not all Rcpp committers watch questions here.

Answer (score 26):

I would tend to use a compressed variation of Dirk's solution:

```
using namespace Rcpp ;
return List::create( 
   _["vec"]  = someVector, 
   _["lst"]  = someList, 
   _["vec2"] = someOtherVector
 ) ;
```

Also, to come back to the original question, `vector< vector<int> >` should wrap itself to a list of integer vectors, not a matrix. See:

```
require( Rcpp )
require( inline )
require( RUnit )

fx <- cxxfunction( , '

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v ;

    std::vector<int> x1(1) ; v.push_back( x1 );
    std::vector<int> x2(2) ; v.push_back( x2 );
    std::vector<int> x3(3) ; v.push_back( x3 );

    return wrap( v ) ;

', plugin = "Rcpp" )
```

I get :

```
> fx() 

[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0
```